# How to solve no such file or directory while using xargs

Tags: xargs, cp

I am trying to copy a file(s) to the same directory but with a prefix. I am using xargs to do that. NOTE: I can't use `cd` as it will break build in my pipeline.
This is what I have

```
root@gotoadmins-OU:~# ls
snap  test

root@gotoadmins-OU:~# ls test/
me.war

root@gotoadmins-OU:~# ls test | xargs -I {} cp {} latest-{} test/
cp: cannot stat 'me.war': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'latest-me.war': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Well, there is indeed no `me.war` (but there is a `test/me.war`), nor a `latest-me.war`. What did you expect?

Comment: [Don’t use `ls` like that.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `I can't use cd as it will break build in my pipeline.` Please research subshells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply want to copy all of the files in a subdirectory to the same subdirectory, but with the prefix "latest-".

```sh
find test -type f -execdir bash -c 'cp "$1" latest-"$(basename "$1")"' "$(which bash)" "{}" \;
```

`$(which bash)` can be replaced with the word `bash` or anything, really. It's just a placeholder.

As @KamilCuk commented, a subshell might also be an option. If you put commands inside parentheses (e.g. `(cd test; for FILE in *; do cp "$FILE" latest-"$FILE"; done)`), those commands are run in a subshell, so the environment, including your working directory, is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

can you just use the cp command to do this?

```
cp test/me.war test/latest-me.war
```